# How to use Cloudfront as https endpoint for an slack App

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, slack, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I've created a Slack app. If i want that this app can be installed in other workspaces i have to add Oauth which basically translates into expose an https endpoint. Until now my app is served from AWS Faregate: i have an image in the container registry and one service is expose through a ALB (http endpoint) and in this way all work perfect, Slack make a first endpoint validation when you configure It and this approach works. Because i need the https if i configure a cloudfront in front of the ALB in order to archieve the https endpoint, with this configuration the verification try reach the container but It give a non valid error. Do you now if this is because the cloudfront make something weird with the request? Thanks a lot

I've tries connection the ALB to a cloudfront distribución with a https url

Comment: If you already have an ALB then you just need to add a port 443 listener to the ALB and add a free AWS ACM certificate to the listener. There is no need for CloudFront in that scenario.